# Not able to pass data from controller to View

Tags: angularjs

Can you let me know why the below line of code is not working

```
$http.get($scope.user1.repos_url).then(OnRepos,OnReposErr);
```

Here is the below module and for full code please see the given Plunker link
https://plnkr.co/edit/4jnawDJgdMM61GYfpxor?p=preview

```
angular.module('MyTestApp',[]).controller('MainController',


function MainController($scope,$http) {

  var OnUserComplete = function (response ) {
    $scope.user1 = response.data ;
    $http.get($scope.user1.repos_url).then(OnRepos,OnReposErr);
  };


  var OnRepos = function(reponse) {    
    $scope.repos = response.data ;
  };


  $scope.searchFn = function(userName) {
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + userName ).then(OnUserComplete,OnError);
  };


}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo on your success method, it is **`response`** not **`reponse`**

```
var OnRepos = function(response) {  
  $scope.repos = response.data ;
};
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXH9ej622pDRwZyJWSnp?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks.As i am new can yu let me know how can i identify the error?By looking into the console log?

Comment: Yes it throws an error in console as you hit the button as repose not defined. then you need to check the variable. taht's it. mark if that helped

Answer (score 0):

The spelling of response is wrong,

```
var OnRepos = function(response) {  
  $scope.repos = response.data ;
};
```

[image: Check console for error]

Comment: dude what is different from the answer i posted above?

Comment: dude i already started answering and inbetween i got hooked somewhere, five minutes later, i posted it. That's when i saw you already posted.

Comment: ok that happens, i was wondering if it is different, tbh no need to have two same answers